# How to calculate month with fraction in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to write a function that receives two arguments `startdate` and `enddate` where it returns the difference between these two dates.

Say that function is `monthfractiondiff(startdate,enddate)`

e.g. `monthfractiondiff(15/01/2016,15/02/2016)` will return
`((31-15)/31)+(15/29) = 1.0333704116`

`monthfractiondiff(15/11/2018,15/02/2019)` will return
`((30-15)/30)+1+1+(15/28) = 3.0357142857`

I vainly tried https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=113589

Comment: Post the actual code you've tried and indicate what part of it isn't working correctly. "Vainly tried" could be a typo in what you retyped, it could be that you missed a line in copy/paste, it's hard to tell...

Comment: @FreeMan I tried above code(as posted by pstraton) it works when both the start and end date are in the same year but it goes wrong when both dates are in different years e.g. startdate in 2018 and enddate in 2019.

Comment: Have a look to the thread you are mentioning, scroll down and try the code of user *pstraton*.

Comment: thank you for response. updated my comment.does it work really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** thanks to other answer WeeBee

```
Function HowManyMonths(startdate As Date, Enddate As Date) As Double
Dim pctSTARTmonth As Double, pctENDmonth As Double, M As Long


'caputues percentage of month
pctSTARTmonth = Day(startdate) / Day(DateSerial(Year(startdate), Month(startdate) + 1, 1) - 1)
pctENDmonth = Day(Enddate) / Day(DateSerial(Year(Enddate), Month(Enddate) + 1, 1) - 1)


'Use Date difference function to get whole number and then combine perc
HowManyMonths = DateDiff("M", startdate, Enddate) + pctENDmonth - pctSTARTmonth


End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! but it also do not calculate the correct fraction of month e.g. HowManyMonths(03 December 2018, 17 June 2019) returns `6.5032` which would be `29/31+1+1+1+1+1+17/30 = 6.50215053762 or 6.5022`

Comment: @SIslam that's a different approach than what you said previously. In your first example with November you did total days subtract date divided by total days so: `(30-15)/30=0.5`. But with your December 3 example you show 29/31 which is a different approach. Based on your previous example it would be which equals 28, instead you `31-2` to get 29 over 31. This would explain your difference. If you want to include the start date (as you did for your December examples) it's easy to change.

Comment: `monthfractiondiff(15/01/2016,15/02/2016) will return ((31-15)/31)+(15/29) = 1.0333704116` Here `(31-15) = (Total Days in that month)-Day portion of the start date`

Comment: @SIslam sorry, I don't understand. Good luck with it.

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand. `monthfractiondiff(15/01/2016,15/02/2016)` will return `((31-15)/31)+(15/29) = 1.0333704116` Here `(31-15) = (Total Days in January month)-(Day portion of the start date i.e. 15)`

Comment: Yeah I see that... Jan 15 to Feb 15 in a leap year equals 1.0337 (31-15) = 16/31 + 15/29.That's what my formula returns, and that's what you listed as the expected result in your example. That's not the same approach in your December 3 example which is = (31-3) = that shows TWENTY-NINE instead of 28 divided by 31.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with datediff().

```
datediff("d", "01/01/2019", date())/30.5
```

Today this returns me 4,85245901639344.

Comment: I like your overall approach better (i.e. standadizing the month), but the OP makes it clear that he/she is looking for each month to be converted to a percentage in relative days of month. Your formula doesn't quite fit as it would return 1.0163 for the Jan/Feb example instead of 1.0337.

Comment: Yeah, My formula don't have your level of accuracy, it's math approach.

Comment: I stole part of your answer (And paid for it with an upclick!). The `DateDiff` is a better approach than my loop idea.

Comment: Thanks, @PGCodeRider!

Answer (score 1):

As the day count of months varies, you have to count by days to get as close as possible, as there never (except within a month or within July/August or December/January) will be an exact value:

```
' Rounds by default to two decimals, as more decimals has no meaning
' due to the varying count of days of a month.
' Optionally, don't round, by setting Round2 to False.
'
Public Function TotalMonths( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional Round2 As Boolean = True) _
    As Double

    Dim Months      As Double
    Dim Part1       As Double
    Dim Part2       As Double
    Dim Fraction    As Double
    Dim Result      As Double

    Months = DateDiff("m", Date1, Date2)
    Part1 = (Day(Date1) - 1) / DaysInMonth(Date1)
    Part2 = (Day(Date2) - 1) / DaysInMonth(Date2)

    If Round2 = True Then
        ' Round to two decimals.
        Fraction = (-Part1 + Part2) * 100
        Result = Months + Int(Fraction + 0.5) / 100
    Else
        Result = Months - Part1 + Part2
    End If

    TotalMonths = Result

End Function


' Returns the count of days of the month of Date1.
'
' 2016-02-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DaysInMonth( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date) _
    As Integer

    Const MaxDateValue  As Date = #12/31/9999#
    Const MaxDayValue   As Integer = 31

    Dim Days    As Integer

    If DateDiff("m", Date1, MaxDateValue) = 0 Then
        Days = MaxDayValue
    Else
        Days = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date1), Month(Date1) + 1, 0))
    End If

    DaysInMonth = Days

End Function
```

Results:

```
? TotalMonths(#2016/01/15#, #2016/02/15#)
 1.03 

? TotalMonths(#2018/11/15#, #2019/02/15#)
 3.03
```

Comment: Seems like quite the effort to get `DaysInMonth`. See my approach below: `Day(DateSerial(Year(startdate), Month(startdate) + 1, 1) - 1)`

Comment: @PGCodeRider: It's taken from a structured library.